# Dual monitors on laptop via Thunderbolt

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, laptop, thunderbolt

Running 16.04 on a Dell XPS 13. I have one monitor connected with a Thunderbolt --> HDMI adapter. What hardware do I need to connect two external monitors via Thunderbolt? Is there even support for this right now?

Comment: Sort of. DisplayPort (carried by Thunderbolt/USB-C) has support for [daisy-chaining](https://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/), but I'm not sure if that's supported in hardware. Actual docks that make use of the Thunderbolt (like Dell's TB-16) will definitely allow you to use multiple monitors (disclaimer, I'm using one right now).

Comment: Yeah, I see a bunch of outputs listed in `xrandr`, so I figured it was at least supported. Just wanted to make sure it worked before I expense a dock or something.

Comment: @KazWolfe In case I wanted to reconstruct your known-working setup, specifically which laptop model, dock, cables, monitors, and OS are you using?

Comment: @JeffG Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running the HWE kernel. I am using a Dell XPS 9550 with a TB-16. All monitors are Dell-branded (but this should theoretically work with anything) and connected thru DisplayPort, though HDMI does work. I did need to disable Thunderbolt security in the BIOS, and there are still a few bugs with the dock (namely, USB and Ethernet are somewhat flaky).

Comment: On [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946022/problems-connecting-multiple-monitors-through-mst-hubs) he has two external monitors working fine with a Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI hub/splitter. The problem is setting up a third. So yes I'd say it works for two monitors in your situation.