# Problems connecting multiple monitors through MST hubs

Tags: multiple-monitors, thunderbolt

I have have dell XPS 15 (9550) laptop with a Nvidia GTX1050 graphics card that has a thunderbolt 3 and one HDMI port. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on this machine. I want to drive 3 QHD (2560 x 1440) monitors. In order to do this, I purchased a [startech usb c MST hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XPVGQKY). I was able to connect 2 of my monitors using this MST hub. I connected the third monitor to my HDMI port.

I am having problems with my setup. The 2 monitors connected to the MST hub work as expected as long as I do not connect the third monitor to my HDMI port. Once I connect my third monitor, the other 2 monitors cut out. Any advise on troubleshooting this problem will be a great help.

Comment: Disconnect everything you can. Issue the command `journalctl --follow | tee /tmp/journalctl.log`. Then connect things back, waiting a minute or two between connections. Kill the `journalctl`, read `/tmp/journalctl.log`

Comment: +1 because I just ordered a Dell with Thunderbolt 3 and hope to have it drive secondary external HDMI TV via adapter and first (main) HDMI TV via HDMI port. The laptop screen would be primary display via LVDS in this three screen setup. I'm curious how your problem solving is progressing?